# Can't start tomcat6 on Fedora12, how to allow through firewall?

Tags: firewall, fedora, tomcat6

I've got a fedora 12 system, and have installed tomcat6 via yum.

I can start tomcat by issuing: `tomcat6 start`

I can see this is OK by the `catalina.out` log file as follows

```
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8888
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 287 ms
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8888
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/14  config=null
Nov 20, 2009 11:05:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 91 ms
```

I have changed the port for tomcat to 8888 as 8080 is in use elsewhere, I have changed this in `server.xml` as follows

```
 <Connector port="8888"
            protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
            connectionTimeout="20000" 
            redirectPort="8443" />
```

I can't get anything on http://localhost:8888 in any browser, I'm thinking that the firewall could have been blocking tomcat. I've disabled the firewall temporarily in `system-config-firewall` and restarted tomcat, but that doesn't seem to change anything

What else could be stopping access to tomcat? There is nothing in `/var/log/messages` regarding tomcat other than the yum install logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought the firewall would block loopback connections, but just in case: are you sure it's disabled? Try running (as root): `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`

Also, are you sure the Tomcat process is still running? Check with: `ps aux | grep java`

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient privs, try

netstat -an | grep LIST

and see if there is actually anything listening on port 8888. If so, try "127.0.0.1:8888" in your browser where you are now trying "localhost".